# SQL join without multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I've three tables like DATA, SATURATION, VALUE, where:

```
CREATE TABLE DATA(
  data_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY(data_id)
);

CREATE TABLE VALUE(
  value_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  data_id INT,
  sample INT,
  channel_1 DOUBLE,
  channel_2 DOUBLE,
  channel_3 DOUBLE,
  PRIMARY KEY (value_id),
  FOREIGN KEY(data_id) REFERENCES DATA(data_id)
);

CREATE TABLE SATURATION(
  saturation_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  data_id INT,
  sample INT,
  channel_1 INT CHECK (channel_1 >= 0 AND channel_1 <= 1),
  channel_2 INT CHECK (channel_2 >= 0 AND channel_2 <= 1),
  channel_3 INT CHECK (channel_3 >= 0 AND channel_2 <= 3),
  PRIMARY KEY (saturation_id),
  FOREIGN KEY(data_id) REFERENCES DATA(data_id)
);
```

I've query like:

```
SELECT s.sample AS 'S Sample', s.channel_1 AS '#Ch_1 S', s.channel_2 AS '#Ch_2 ES', s.channel_3 AS '#Ch_3 ES',
  v.sample AS 'V Sample', v.channel_1 AS '#Ch_1 V', v.channel_2 AS '#Ch_2 V', v.channel_3 AS '#Ch_3 V'
FROM VALUE v
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SATURATION s
  ON v.data_id = s.data_id
  WHERE s.sample = v.sample AND s.data_id = 1;
```

Result is okay, if the number of samples are equal in one series. But I want something like this:

```
-----------
| ES Sample | #Ch_1 ES | #Ch_2 ES | #Ch_3 ES | EV Sample | #Ch_1 EV | #Ch_2 EV | #Ch_3 EV |
-----------
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 114.5 | 10.2 | 114.5 |
-----------
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 114.5 | 10.2 | 114.5 |
-----------
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 3 | 114.5 | 10.2 | 114.5 |
-----------
| 4 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 4 | 114.5 | 10.2 | 114.5 |
-----------
| null | null | null | null | 5 | 114.5 | 10.2 | 114.5 |
-----------
```

How to do it? Normally without clause 's.sample = v.sample' i get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHMd2.png). I don't want store saturation and value in one table but this very simple and foolish solution I guess.

**UPDATE:**

Here's a query which produce [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bh7R6.png) as I wanted (if I have more values in one serie than saturations):

```
SELECT v.data_id AS 'V ID', s.data_id AS 'S ID', s.sample AS 'S Sample', s.channel_1 AS '#Ch_1 S', s.channel_2 AS '#Ch_2 S', s.channel_3 AS '#Ch_3 S',
  v.sample AS 'V Sample', v.channel_1 AS '#Ch_1 V', v.channel_2 AS '#Ch_2 V', v.channel_3 AS '#Ch_3 V'
FROM SATURATION s RIGHT JOIN VALUE v ON v.sample = s.sample
WHERE (v.data_id = 1 OR s.data_id IS NULL) AND (s.data_id = 1 OR s.data_id IS NULL);
```

Comment: Is a Sample a thing, which might have value data and saturation data or both (where you might want to add a sample table, a fk to both value and saturation tables, and drive the query from this, left joining to the other tables), or is each type a separate sample? (In which case what you are doing is getting two unrelated series and putting them side by side? Then a FULL OUTER JOIN might do what you asked, but is prob not the real solution, this is probably something that should be done in the application layer not the sql

Comment: @JamesCasey, sample is a thing which might have value data and saturation or both. But sometimes we can lose sample of value / satur. when we're gathering data from device. So application layer should merge this two queries below into one table with 8 columns? As I want?

`SELECT es.sample AS 'S Sample', s.channel_1 AS '#Ch_1 S', s.channel_2 AS '#Ch_2 S', s.channel_3 AS '#Ch_3 S'
FROM SATURATION s
WHERE s.data_id = 1;`
`SELECT  v.sample AS 'V Sample', v.channel_1 AS '#Ch_1 V', v.channel_2 AS '#Ch_2 V', v.channel_3 AS '#Ch_3 V'
FROM VALUE v
WHERE v.data_id = 1;`

Answer (score 0):

I would create a sample table between data and value and saturation. So a Data would have many Samples, each of which would have zero or one Value and zero or one Saturation records

Then drive the query from this Sample table, left joining to both Value and Saturation.

Let me know if this doesn't make sense and I will try to clarify, but hopefully you see what I mean.

Comment: Yeah, probably this will be fine and solve my problem in elegant way but I I came up with a query which produce result as I wanted. I've updated first post already. You can take a look!

Comment: I think you have just reversed the problem, by doing right join instead of left join you will now get an issue if there are more saturations than values (or the other way around :) ) - you can use FULL OUTER JOIN to get what you want though which will handle missing data either way